The “Goodyear Airship Operations Manual”
I’m using ASA’s products to prepare for the AGI and IGI knowledge tests.  They often contain questions about airships and reference a document called the Goodyear Airship Operations Manual.  I’m already familiar with the K-Type Airship Pilot Manual which the FAA uses as a handbook (I presume) for LTA Airship training but I have not heard of the former document.  Does this thing exist and does someone have a copy of it as a PDF?  Thanks

Okay, even without studying for a new license, that sounds like a cool document to peruse!

The current Goodyear blimp is a Zeppelin NT semi-rigid airship. If you look for that instead of "Goodyear Blimp" you will find, among other things, the EASA type certificate EASA-AS-001, and it contains an excellent starting point for what you are trying to find.
